# Are there any examples of Starfleet officers who were captains or admirals without ever having been in command of a starship or base?

Tags: star-trek, starfleet-rank

The question says it all - from my experience watching the shows, but not reading any books or other media, all "captains" are captains of ships. Is it possible for a starfleet officer to be promoted to captain and then admiral without being in command of a ship or base?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Montgomery [Scott](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Montgomery_Scott) achieved the rank of Captain without serving as a ship's captain. He was referred to as a Captain of Engineering while serving on the Excelsior as chief engineer while holding the rank of Captain.

Likewise, McCoy became an admiral by the time of TNG without any indication of command experience.

Comment: I'm not sure we can say for certain that McCoy never had any command experience? He could conceivably have been captain of a hospital ship or something similar between ST6 and TNG. Something like Crusher's ship in the All Good Things future timeline.

Comment: Scotty is definitely a good example, thanks!

Comment: @Idran: edited slightly to reflect your comment

Comment: I had a weird nightmare about a cadet getting promoted to Captain just because his action figure was already trademarked with that rank!

Comment: In real life militaries doctors are often promoted to high rank without any command responsibilities (except over other medical staff). Doctors don't command ships - they are too valuable to waste their time doing that.

Comment: I agree with that.

Comment: @DJClayworth Not only no command responsibilities, but also no command rights. Doctors are [staff officers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Navy_staff_corps). If the CO, XO, and other senior officers are lost, command responsibility follows the unrestricted line down to the last ensign, rather than pass to high-ranking restricted or staff officers.

Comment: TIL that the US Navy used to have a Corps of Professors of Mathematics.  I can see why they might want to exclude them from the line of command responsibility.  "Sir, the bridge officers are all dead!  What are your orders?"  "Okay, let's turn left to a heading of 2.47 radians..."

Answer (score 5):

[Philippa Louvois](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phillipa_Louvois), the Judge Advocate who presided over Data's trial on whether or not he is property held the rank of captain.

There should likely be MORE Captains in specialties (medical, legal, engineering, various sciences, Logistics, etc) than those who command a starship just like their are plenty of Colonels who never were commanders in the Army for example.

Comment: You can add https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Krasnovsky to this list of non-command captains.

Comment: @Valorum According to the Memory Alpha article you linked, Krasnovsky was introduced as a "Star Ship Captain": "He was to have been introduced, in dialogue from the final draft script, as a 'Star Command Captain', though this was changed to 'Star Ship Captain' in the revised final draft." Wouldn't that mean that he actually _was_ Captain of a Starship?